# Sum of Martingale Bounds

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have the Martingale bounds for backlog and delay, respectively. Could I sum the bounds values to obtain a bound of the backlog+delay curve?

Comment: It would help to give a concrete example and to explain what you mean by "backlog" and "delay." As it stands this is a rather vague question.

Comment: @Math1000 I have a computation system in which the backlog is defined as $Q(n)=sup_{n \geq 0}\{A(n)-S(n)\}$, and the delay as $W(n)=\min\{k \geq 0|A(n-k) \leq D(n)\}$, in which $D(n)$ are the system departures and $A(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i$ and $S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}s_i$ are the arrivals and the service process, respectively, considering i.i.d random variables for both $A$ and $S$.The bounds for the backlog is $P(Q\geq\sigma)$, and the bound for the delay is  $P(W(n) \geq k)$. My goal is a bound for the overall time spent by a task in the computation system, i.e., $P(W(n)+Q(n) \geq k)$.